# Understanding the consistency between gcc and glibc

Tags: gcc, build, glibc

I work on a relatively old system:

- `gcc --version` prints `4.1.2 20080704`).
- `ldd --version` prints `ldd (GNU libc) 2.5`.

I am hoping to download and use a newer version of gcc (latest stable version is `4.8.0`).

Why question is, when building or **using** `gcc` to compile other tools/program, to what extent do I need to be concerned about the version of `glibc` that I am using it with?

More generally, what problems can I encounter if I update one but not the other, and how can I find out which versions of `glibc` a given version of `gcc` work well with each other?

In case it matters, I do not have admin rights on the machine where I work, so I  would need to do the upgrades manually.

Comment: GCC largely adapts to the C library provided by the system — it should work fine with GNU `libc` that you mention, unless there's something in the documentation that says otherwise.  On non-Linux platforms, GCC doesn't necessarily have GNU `libc` to work with; it adapts to what is provided.

Comment: `libc` version shouldn't really matter while building `gcc`.  However, there are other prerequisites that you may wish to check (http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html).